# What is the white powdery stuff that leaks out of a battery if I accidentally submerge it in water?

Tags: batteries

Does it mean that the battery has exploded?

I often see the white powdery stuff when I see "battery disposal" boxes in public areas

Comment: I think that means your battery was being used to smuggle cocaine

Comment: what chemistry is the battery?  alkaline or something else?

Comment: Yeah - one of the standard AAA/AA alkaline batteries

Answer (score 2):

In the case of e.g. a lead acid battery the powder is probably lead/zinc/alimuinium sulphate. In an alkaline battery it might be potassium hydroxide.
With most batteries (e.g. batteries used in consumer products) it is usually a sign of failure (leakage) and the need to replace/dispose of it.
With e.g. a car lead acid battery I don't think this is always the case, sometimes it may just need some attention as small amount of corrosion on the terminals is often expected and can be dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Zinc–carbon batteries (pre-alkaline) used Ammonium chloride as electrolyt. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_chloride